# NSButton object in NSViewController not work

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am learning to write a **MacOS Program without xib**, I have written JavaScript before.

**ViewControllerTest.swift**

```
class ViewControllerTest: NSViewController {
    lazy var button2 = NSButton(frame: NSMakeRect(455, 100, 50, 20))

    override func loadView() {
        ...
        button2.title = "2"
        self.view.addSubview(button2)
        button2.target = self
        button2.action = #selector(self.button2Action)

    }

    @objc public func button2Action () {
        NSLog("Button 2")
    }
}
```

**window.swift**

```
class Window: NSWindow {
    @objc public func button1Action () {
        NSLog("button 1")
    }

    init() {
        ...
        // Button 1
        let button1 = NSButton(frame: NSMakeRect(455, 400, 50, 20))
        button1.title = "1"
        self.contentView!.addSubview(button1)
        button1.target = self
        button1.action = #selector(self.button1Action)

        // add view
        let viewController = ViewControllerTest()
        self.contentView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
    }
}

class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        self.window!.delegate = self
    }
}
```

[image: window image]

I click button 1, console output "Button 1", but button 2 does not work. Any ideas why?
I am have been searching for a long time on net. But no use. Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the view controller released at the end of `init`?

Comment: Also, does `override func loadView()` invoke `super.loadView()` at some point? Footnote: it's better to override `viewDidLoad()` for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat but I think I figured it out. Put your

```
let viewController = ViewControllerTest()
```

outside of the `init()` and it should work now